# netbeans: revert project changes from a special date

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, repository, history

I am using Netbeans IDE to write a java program. I did some modifications in my project in last 2 days ago(yesterday). Now I want to undo these changes. I see all files of project files have a history that contains about 2 days archive. I did not used SVN or GIT. Is there any clean way to retrieve my my project to a time about yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try netbeans's Local History to revert your code. Read [this article](http://jetbrains.dzone.com/news/using-local-history-restore-de) to using Local History to restore deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only work on a file-by-file basis with Netbean's local history. Use a SCM like GIT.

Answer (score 0):

R.Click on project name then click on

```
Subversion -> Revert Modifications
```

now you can check as follows:
[image]

here you can revert all change local with new files on first option

second option to go back to specific commit

third option to go back to specific commits rang

hope that help